# Piping and forking in python

Tags: python, fork, piping

I'm trying to write a program in python that writes 2 integers into the pipe via the parent function and then reads those same integers through the child function. The child function is then supposed to print out the product of the two.

The problem is,when i run it, it waits the 5 seconds like it's supposed to but then returns a value of 441 instead of 2.

Hope somebody can help figure out how to fix this code :)

```
import os,time

def child(pipein):
    while True:
        num1 = int(os.read(pipein,32))
        num2 = int(os.read(pipein,32))
        r=(num1)*(num2)
        print(r)
        os._exit(0)

def parent():
    pipein,pipeout = os.pipe()
    x=5
    if os.fork()==0:
        child(pipein)
    else:
        while True:
            num1=str(2)
            num2=str(1)
            line=os.write(pipeout,num1.encode())
            line=os.write(pipeout,num2.encode())
            time.sleep(x)   

parent()
```

Comment: If you want someone to help you'll need to reduce the question. You should try explaining how it's not working, the way you expect it to behave and your reasoning why. You still may get an answer but threading questions are very non-trivial and expecting someone to do the grunt work for you isn't going to endear you to this community.

Comment: Your new version exits the child after the first pair of `read`s, so it's going to block forever after printing the first value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I would make of it;

```
from __future__ import print_function  #(1)
import os  #(2)
import sys
import time


def child(pipein):  # (3)
    num1 = int(os.read(pipein, 32))  # (6)
    num2 = int(os.read(pipein, 32))
    r = num1 * num2
    print("r = {}".format(r))
    print("Child says bye.") 
    sys.stdout.flush()  # (4)
    os._exit(0)  # (5)


def parent():
    pipein, pipeout = os.pipe()
    x = 1
    if os.fork() == 0:
        print("Launching child")
        child(pipein)
    else:  # (7)
        print("In parent")
        num1 = str(2)  # (8)
        num2 = str(1)
        os.write(pipeout, num1)
        os.write(pipeout, num2)
        print("Parent goes to sleep")
        time.sleep(x)
        print("Parent says bye.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent()
```

1. This is required to make the `print()` *function* work in Python 2.x
2. Style: imports should each be on a separate line
3. No need for a loop if you're going to `exit()` after the first iteration
4. Otherwise the print might not show up.
5. Style: use two blank lines after a function.
6. Style: use a space after a comma, unless it's at the end of a line.
7. Remove the while loop, or you'll be in an infinite loop.
8. Style: use spaces around operators.

With these modifications I get the following output;

```
In parent
Launching child
Parent goes to sleep
r = 2
Child says bye.
Parent says bye.
```

If you want to use multiple processes, it is generally a much better idea to use the `multiprocessing` module. It has objects for processes and process pools, and communication objects like queues and pipes. Queues are first-in first-out, and they are synchronized; so if you put two items in, you can read two items.

Comment: If you want to make this work in Python 2, you definitely don't want to call `encode` on a `str`.

Comment: More importantly, this doesn't actually solve the problem, and introduces a _new_ problem (the parent can quit while the child is still running). If the first `read` happens to grab the entire `'21'` (as it usually will on most platforms), the child will never print anything.

Comment: thank you very much for your help!i've actually picked up a lot from your solution :)

Comment: @abarnert The `str.encode()` works fine in python 2. I agree that it's useless, since no encoding is provided. So it will use the default string encoding.

Comment: @RolandSmith: Unless your code accepts 8-bit input (which only a handful of special cases like `bz2` do), `str.encode` "works" by first silently `decode(sys.getdefaultencoding())`-ing and then doing your `encode` on the result. Meanwhile, in your edited version _without_ the `encode`, it's a `TypeError` in Python 3.x, because `os.write` takes a `bytes`, not a `str`. Really, why are you trying to force a Python 3 novice to write Python 2.x-compatible code in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that your child has an infinite loop, reading `num1` over and over forever (or, rather, reading it twice and then blocking forever on a third input that will never come) before doing anything.

Fix that by moving more of the code into the `while` loop, like this:

```
def child(pipein):
    while True:
        num1 = int(os.read(pipein,32))
        num2 = int(os.read(pipein,32))
        r=(num1)*(num2)
        print(r)
```

And you might as well remove the `os._exit(0)`, because you're never going to reach it anyway.

---

Your next problem is that your encoding and decoding steps don't match. You'll get away with this as long as your `sys.getdefaultencoding()` is something that's a strict superset of ASCII (or, really, as long as its digits match ASCII digits), but you really shouldn't silently rely on that.

---

Next, `os.read(pipein,32)` can give you the results of a single write, or it can give you the results of up to 32 separate writes combined together. The fact that `write` (of up to PIPE_BUF) is guaranteed be atomic doesn't help you—it just means you can't end up with the first half of a write and not the second half.

So, most likely, you'll get the `21` in `num1`, and then 5 seconds later get another `21` in `num2`, so instead of printing out `2` every 5 seconds, you'll print out `441` every 10 seconds. But even that isn't guaranteed.

Pipes, like TCP sockets, are [byte streams, not message streams](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html). Which means you need to build some kind of protocol.

---

There are two really obvious choices here.

First, since you're already reading a fixed record size of (up to) 32 bytes, why not write a fixed record size of exactly 32 bytes? Just change your `str` lines to something that generates a string of exactly 32 characters that will be encoded to 32 bytes in any encoding that already works, and will parse as a single integer of the appropriate value. Like this:

```
num1 = format(2, '32d')
num2 = format(1, '32d')
```

Alternatively, each record can be a pair of whitespace-separated numbers, and records can be separated with newlines. That's trivial to parse. Especially since you're not using non-blocking pipes or anything, so you can just put a file object around them and make it all easy.

Comment: thanks a lot!!it now makes a lot more sense.I actually just started learning python a few weeks ago and your solution has helped me a lot!